# static_cast an interface to derived class

Tags: c++, static-cast

I am trying to static_cast an interface object into object of derived class which inherits that interface.  I am getting an error

> 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'IInherit *' to 'cDerived *'

The derived class and interface are of the following format.

```
class cDerived: public IInherit
{
    Repo* p_Repos;
public:
    cDerived(Repo* pRepos)
    {
        p_Repos = pRepos;
    }
    Repo* GetRepo()
    {
            return p_Repos;
    }
    void doAction(ITok*& pTc)
    {
       ///some logic
    }

}

class IInherit
{
public:
    virtual ~IInherit() {}
    virtual void doAction(ITok*& pTc)=0;
};
```

I have a `vector<IInherit*>` object accessible in the code through getInherit() method such that the type of  getInherit()[0] is cDerived* 
I am performing static cast using the expression:

```
Repo* pRep= static_cast<cDerived*>(getInherit()[0])->GetRepo();
```

I am not sure if it is possible to static_cast as interface object. Is there any other way that I would be able to perform this cast?

Comment: What compiler are you using? This [works for me](http://ideone.com/ESohQ3).

Comment: Can you provide a complete example showing the error and the full error message?

Comment: Are the **definitions** of `IInherit` and `cDerived` both visible at the point where the error occurs?

Comment: By chance, is the real problem because you declared IInherit in your header file AFTER you declared cDerived as you did above?  Or is that just how you cut&paste in the code above.  There's a missing semi-colon after the delclaration of cDerived. I'm just wondering if compiler is erroring out on some other error before showing this error.

Comment: No I have forward declared the derived class, no issues with visibility

Comment: @KevinBallard vc++ compiler

Comment: Why do you need to call `GetRepo()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `static_cast` in your example.

But you must include *both definitions* of `IInherit` and `cDerived` for it to work. The compiler must see, that `cDerived` inherits from `IInherit`. Otherwise, it cannot decide that the `static_cast` is indeed valid.

```
#include <vector>

struct R {};
struct B {};
struct D : public B {
    R *getR() { return new R(); }
};

void f()
{
    std::vector<B*> v;
    v.push_back(new D());
    D *d = static_cast<D*>(v[0]);
    R *r = d->getR();
}
```

---

If the members of vector are always of derived type, you might also consider using a `vector<cDerived*>` instead. This would avoid the cast altogether:

```
std::vector<D*> v;
v.push_back(new D());
R *r = v[0]->getR();
```

Comment: This is the answer. static_cast requires more than a forward declaration to ensure the cast is at least possible (though you could still be lying to the compiler).

Comment: @vaibhavkumar Visibility alone is not the issue, the compiler must see the definition, i.e. the inheritance. I updated my answer.